# Subclassing django choicefield doesn't work

Tags: python, django, subclass, choicefield

I'm trying to subclass the ChoiceField so I can use it in multiple forms (DRY). For example:

```
class testField(forms.ChoiceField):
  choices = (('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'))
  label = "test"

class testForm(forms.Form):
  test = testField()
```

Other types of Fields work as subclasses (such as CharField), however when rendering the subclass of ChoiceField I get an obscure error:

```
AttributeError at /..url.../
'testField' object has no attribute '_choices'
```

Specifying the `choices` as `_choices` in the subclass doesn't report the error, but nor does it display the contents in the rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mess with the `Field`'s class properties, `choices` is an attribute of a `ChoiceField` instance. Override `__init__(...)` instead, as advised in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#creating-custom-fields):

```
class TestField(ChoiceField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['choices'] = ((1, 'a'), (2, 'b'))
        kwargs['label'] = "test"
        super(TestField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class TestForm(Form):
    test = TestField()

f = TestForm()

f.fields['test'].choices
> [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b')]

f.fields['test'].label
> 'test'
```